# How to stop sharing sessions with multiple Edge browsers

Tags: session, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

How do I disable browser session sharing in Edge browser? In IE 11 or earlier, I could open a new window and open my web application and log into it. Then open another IE window and log in as a different user in my application and work parallel. I have to do few settings changes and I am good to go.

How to do the same in Edge? Are there any settings or registry update for this?

Comment: Hope my question is clear. Any updates?

Comment: FYI - Edge is not a new version of IE, it is a totally different browser. Also, this question should be asked on Superuser since it is just about general application use. https://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You could launch an InPrivate (Incognito) session to do this.

Comment: By default all InPrivate windows will share the same session unfortunately.

Comment: @TheFrost Exact, I have the same problem: if you just need 2 different session it works but if you need 3 or more, the `InPrivate` windows are all shared. This seems to be also the case with Chrome (logical as they share the same engine).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have more than two independent sessions, I think there's no other alternative than using an extension.

As MS-Edge can share the same extensions as Chrome, you can add [SessionBox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-multi-login-to/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig?hl=en-US) to your Edge browser.

I found this very useful extension from [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1391164/196634) and now I am able to share several session in the same Chrome/Edge window.